Единственное или множественное число существительных в данном предложении?
Известно, что Иванов в разные годы был начальником то одного отдела, то другого, то третьего. В каком числе должны стоять существительные, если мы передаём эту информацию таким предложением?
Иванов в разные годы занимал должность(должности?) начальника(начальников?) отдела(отделов?).

Правильно:
Известно, что Иванов в разные годы был начальником то одного отдела, то другого, то третьего.
Пояснение

Должность начальника конкретного отдела — это служебное место, которое он занимал последовательно в разное время,  такая должность только одна, поэтому число единственное.
ДО́ЛЖНОСТЬ, -и, род. мн. -е́й, ж. Служебное положение, 
место в каком-л. учреждении, предприятии и т. п. и 
связанные с ним служебные обязанности.


Если в отделе два заместителя начальника отдела, то на эти должности требуются два человека. Множественное число. Аналогично если на фирме несколько отделов, то требуются начальники на эти должности.


Похожая тема:
Назначить на должности аудиторов...
Два аудитора назначаются на две должности (два служебных места), также будут изданы два приказа об их назначении.
Пример:
... пришлось бы назначить на должности командиров батарей малоопытных и совершенно неподготовленных обер-офицеров; [Е. З. Барсуков. Русская артиллерия в мировую войну (1938)]

Спасибо за информацию, но я просила для этого предложения дать ответ - Иванов в разные годы занимал должность(должности?) начальника(начальников?) отдела(отделов?).

Я же дала вам ответ – правильно записанное предложение: "Известно, что Иванов в разные годы был начальником то одного отдела, то другого (отдела), то третьего (отдела)" Варианты с мн. числом там невозможны, иначе сочетаемость слов будет нарушена.

Поняла, что невозможно. Но заменить нужное предложение совершенно левым я не могу :)

А зачем менять? Именно ваше предложение не имеет вариантов, там только ед. число. Как его  записать, используя мн. число? Это просто невозможно.

Sharon, вы просто не то предложение рассмотрели. Нужное выделено курсивом в конце вопроса, да и в комментарии автора оно повторяется.

Какие люди, да разве вы еще с нами?)  // Ну тогда пусть так: Иванов в разные годы занимал  должность начальника отдела  в разных структурах.  А то предложение у вас без контекста, ага)
